# ggpredict : confidence interval for negative binomial models

Tags: intervals

I used the following code to model count data :

```
ModActi<-glmmTMB(Median ~ H_veg + D_veg + Landscape + JulianDay + 
    H_veg:D_veg + (1 | Site), 
    data=MyDataActi, family=nbinom2)
```

I then used the ggpredict function of the ggeffects package to plot the predicted values of my model for the categorical variable "Landscape":

```
pr1 <- ggpredict(ModActi, "Landscape")
plot(pr1)
```

I obtain this [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YccWP.png).

As you can see, lower confidence intervals are negative, as if the function would calculate them for a normal distribution.

In the help menu of ggpredict, it is not clear to me if there is a way to calculate confidence intervals for a negative binomial distribution (as stated in the model) ?

EDIT : if I use glmer in poisson, the confidence intervals are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because *glmmTMB* only returned predictions on the response scale and these were not back transformed. Now *glmmTMB* was update on CRAN and I also revised *ggeffects*. You can try out the current dev-version at https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects, which now properly computes the CI (after updating glmmTMB to version 0.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

My supervisor found a nice solution by recalculating the standard errors in the predict table :

```
pr1 <- ggpredict(ModActi, "Landscape")
Ynontransform=log(pr1$predicted)
SEnontransform=log(pr1$conf.high)-Ynontransform
ConfLow=exp(Ynontransform-SEnontransform)
pr1$conf.low=ConfLow
plot(pr1)
```